# (1/1) NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179

Tags: laravel

I have a problem regarding a system that a previous developer created.
The system is deployed in his own terminal using XAMPP and accessed by many users in our company. The computer where the System is deployed is about to be broken. I plan to transfer it to a server or to my terminal. I installed all the needed applications to create and run a laravel project.

My problem is that when I transferred the application to my terminal, this error shows up when I access it:

`(1/1) NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179`

I tried to create a new project and deploy it but there is no problem.

I tried to copy the existing XAMPP installation, just so all the configurations he made will be copied. But it still doesn't work.

I tried to do `php artisan route:cache` as suggested by the internet.

See codes below(This codes are like what I see in other questions here), I don't know what to show so if ever you guys need any other source codes just ask.

Routes

```
<?php

//USER RESOURCE
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login');
Route::get('/logout', 'UserController@logout');



//DISCONNECT RESOURCE
Route::resource('/disconnections', 'DisconnectionController');
Route::get('/get_freco_datatable', 'DisconnectionController@get_freco_datatable');
Route::get('/get_freco_datatable_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}','DisconnectionController@get_freco_datatable_filtered');
Route::get('/get_account_fbilmast/{acnt_code}', 'DisconnectionController@get_account_fbilmast');
Route::get('/get_freco_datatable_all', 'DisconnectionController@get_freco_datatable_all');
Route::get('/get_for_tagging_table','DisconnectionController@get_for_tagging_table');
Route::get('/get_for_tagging_table_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}','DisconnectionController@get_for_tagging_table_filtered');
Route::post('/save_new_disconnection_from_tagging_table/{id}/{field}/{value?}','DisconnectionController@save_new_disconnection_from_tagging_table');
Route::get('/get_old_freco','DisconnectionController@get_old_freco');
Route::get('/get_total_disconnection_per_book_no_table','DisconnectionController@get_total_disconnection_per_book_no_table');
Route::get('/get_total_disconnection_per_book_no_table_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}','DisconnectionController@get_total_disconnection_per_book_no_table_filtered');


//RECONNECTION RESOURCE
Route::resource('/reconnections', 'ReconnectionController');
Route::get('/get_fdisco_datatable', 'ReconnectionController@get_fdisco_datatable');
Route::get('/get_fdisco_datatable_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}','ReconnectionController@get_fdisco_datatable_filtered');


//SPECIAL RECO DISCO RESOURCE
Route::resource('/special-reco-disco', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController');
Route::get('/createSpecReco/create', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@createSpecReco');
Route::get('/createSpecDisco/create', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@createSpecDisco');
Route::get('/editSpecReco/{id}/edit', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@editSpecReco');
Route::get('/editSpecDisco/{id}/edit', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@editSpecDisco');
Route::delete('/destroySpecReco/{id}', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@destroySpecReco');
Route::delete('/destroySpecDisco/{id}', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@destroySpecDisco');
Route::get('/get_special_disco_datatable', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@get_special_disco_datatable');
Route::get('/get_special_reco_datatable', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@get_special_reco_datatable');
Route::get('/get_special_disco_datatable_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@get_special_disco_datatable_filtered');
Route::get('/get_special_reco_datatable_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}', 'SpecialRecoDiscoController@get_special_reco_datatable_filtered');


//PROMISSORY NOTE RESOURCE
Route::resource('/promissory-notes', 'PromissoryNoteController');
Route::get('/get_fdispn_datatable', 'PromissoryNoteController@get_fdispn_datatable');
Route::get('/get_fdispn_datatable_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}', 'PromissoryNoteController@get_fdispn_datatable_filtered');
Route::get('/get_promissory_note_tagging_table','PromissoryNoteController@get_promissory_note_tagging_table');
Route::get('/get_promissory_note_dispatch_data','PromissoryNoteController@get_promissory_note_dispatch_data');
Route::get('/get_promissory_note_dispatch_data_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}','PromissoryNoteController@get_promissory_note_dispatch_data_filtered');
Route::get('/get_promissory_note_breakdown/{acnt_code}/{pn_id}','PromissoryNoteController@get_promissory_note_breakdown');
Route::get('/add_promissory_note_breakdown_page/{acnt_code}/{pn_id}','PromissoryNoteController@add_promissory_note_breakdown_page');
Route::post('/add_promissory_note_breakdown','PromissoryNoteController@add_promissory_note_breakdown');
Route::post('/update_promissory_note_breakdown/{id}','PromissoryNoteController@update_promissory_note_breakdown');
Route::get('/generate_promissory_note_breakdown/{acnt_code}/{pn_id}/{breakdown}','PromissoryNoteController@generate_promissory_note_breakdown');

//DISPATCH CREW RESOURCE
Route::resource('/dispatch-crew', 'DispatchCrewController');
Route::get('/get_book_no_fbilmast/{book_no}', 'DispatchCrewController@get_book_no_fbilmast');
Route::get('/get_crew_data', 'DispatchCrewController@get_crew_data');
Route::get('/get_crew_data_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}', 'DispatchCrewController@get_crew_data_filtered');
Route::get('/get_crew_dispatch_data/{book_no}/{crew_no}/{crew_name}/{day}', 'DispatchCrewController@get_crew_dispatch_data');
Route::get('/get_saved_generated_dispatch_per_day_data','DispatchCrewController@get_saved_generated_dispatch_per_day_data');
Route::get('/get_saved_generated_dispatch_per_day_data_filtered/{start_date}/{end_date}','DispatchCrewController@get_saved_generated_dispatch_per_day_data_filtered');
Route::get('/get_promissory_note_discon_data','DispatchCrewController@get_promissory_note_discon_data');
Route::get('/get_crew_dispatch_data_test','DispatchCrewController@get_crew_dispatch_data_test');


//DISPATCH RESOURCE
Route::get('/get_dispatch_data', 'DispatchController@get_dispatch_data');


//BILLING INQUIRY RESOURCE
Route::resource('/billing-inquiry','BillingInquiryController');
Route::get('/get_billing_inquiry_datatable','BillingInquiryController@get_billing_inquiry_datatable');
Route::get('/get_billing_ledger_datatable/{account_number}/{start_month?}/{start_year?}/{end_month?}/{end_year?}','BillingInquiryController@get_billing_ledger_datatable');
Route::get('/get_billing_ledger_datatable_json/{account_number}/{start_month?}/{start_year?}/{end_month?}/{end_year?}','BillingInquiryController@get_billing_ledger_datatable_json');


//FAQ
Route::resource('/faq','FAQController');

//PRINT FORMS
Route::get('/get_promissory_note_print_form/{id}/{breakdown}','PromissoryNoteController@get_promissory_note_print_form');
Route::get('/get_dispatch_crew_job_order_form/{book_no}','DispatchCrewController@get_dispatch_crew_job_order_form');
Route::get('/get_reconnection_job_order_form/{acnt_code}','ReconnectionController@get_reconnection_job_order_form');
Route::get('/get_disconnection_grid_form/{row_id?}/{selected?}','DisconnectionController@get_disconnection_grid_form');
Route::get('/get_billing_ledger_form/{account_number}','BillingInquiryController@get_billing_ledger_form');
Route::get('/get_dispatch_crew_job_order_form_test/{book_no}','DispatchCrewController@get_dispatch_crew_job_order_form_test');


//MISCELLANEOUS
Route::get('/dispatch_per_day_update_reconnection','ReconnectionController@dispatch_per_day_update_reconnection');

//Paper Dashboard Test

Route::get('/paper-dashboard', function() {
    return view('paperdashboard');
});
```

I don't know what else I can do with this, since I'm not using laravel to develop systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are getting the `(1/1) NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179` on the root url. If you look at your routes file, there is no route defined to handle root url i.e. '/'. Did you try to visit '/login' and check if it works?

Comment: it works! but when I login I get a new error 
 ```FatalThrowableError Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()
```

Comment: This error means you may have not installed the package [yajra/laravel-oci8](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8). Please check if it is in composer.json and if it is there, then run `composer install`. You can also try to run `composer dump-autoload`. Are you using Oracle with this application?

Comment: yes I am using oracle, I already fixed it :) thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Good to hear that. You are welcome. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Things to do after migrating laravel to new server is:

* *I assume you already run composer install*

1. create the configuration file. Copy the .env.example to .env and start configuring based on your environment
2. cache the config `php artisan config:cache`, also do it every time you change the configuration file
3. I suggest run on Docker instead of XAMPP. I found easier way to develop Laravel App with Docker.
4. `php artisan route:cache` only work if there is no closure on routes.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes composer is already installed, I tried to create a new project and deployed it, I can access it in different computers of the same network. I tried to do ```php artisan config:cache``` but it still doesn't work. Thanks for your help! I'll try it on Docker if it can't be solved

Answer (score 0):

are you accessing the site using `localhost\yourproject\public`? if yes, then try `php artisan serve` on the root directory of your file.

Then it will give you `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, just paste that on browser and you will access your site

Comment: Yes I already tried accessing it using ```http://127.0.0.1:8000```. It doesn't work though the answers above helped me. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: if this answer helped you, please mark it as answer!